# How to start revealing the contents of second div from below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a first fixed div. On scrolling I want to reveal the contents of the second div as if the they were fixed on the first div like on [Conichi](http://www.conichi.com)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saadaziz33/hbxLxu3m/15/)

```css
.one {
  width: 768px;
  height: 700px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  z-idex: -1;
}

.two {
  top: 700px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 768px;
  height: 700px;
  z-index:1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='one'>
    <p>
   What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='two'>
    <p>
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: I have added the fiddle and the efect which is desired. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to re-create the effect you are looking for - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/pdg47xcw/)

CSS

```
.container_1 {
     background-color: black;
   color: #fff;
   z-index:3;
 }
 .container_2 {
     background-color: white;
     z-index:2;
 }
 .container_3 {
     background-color: red;
   color: #CCC;
     z-index:1;
 }
 .container {
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: fixed;
 }
```

jQuery

```
var height = 0,
    divs = 0;

$('.container').each(function(){
    var eachdiv = $(this).outerHeight();
    height += eachdiv;
    divs ++;
});

$('body').css('height',height);

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop <= (height/divs)){
        $('.container_1').css('height',(height/divs)-scrollTop);
    } else if (scrollTop <= (height/divs) * 2) {
        $('.container_1').css('height',0); // if the window scroll goes to quick
        $('.container_2').css('height',(height/divs)*2-scrollTop);
    } else if (scrollTop <= (height/divs) * 3) {
        $('.container_2').css('height',0);
    }// and so on...

});
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="container container_1">
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container container_2">
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container container_3">
      <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks ! :D
Perfekto

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scropllpsy](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/) from Bootstrap, you can see it in action clicking the likn I provided, or, just include bootstrap 4 and:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
 ...
   <div id="navbar-example">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      ...
     </ul>
   </div>
  ...
</body>
```

You can activate it by Javascript:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example' })
```